# how to change disabled access modifier of lang.resx within App-GlobalResources folder to public?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use resources(language) within App-GlobalResources folder. But when i run the project it says this;

> Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.  Type
>   'Resources.lang' is not public or does not contain a public static
>   string property with the name 'Username'.

Access modifier is disabled so i can not change it to public which i think it is the source of problem, i am not sure though.

How can i get it work?

```
For solution:
```

[This works](https://holyhoehle.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/making-global-resources-public/)

Answer (score 0):

Select the file in the Solution Explorer and go to it's properties by right-clicking on the file or by pressing F4.

In the properties window for this file, you can change the access modifier of the file from Protected to Public.

Comment: there is no option to change like access modifier.